# Can't invoke protocol method on generic type restricted by other protocol

Tags: ios, generics, swift-extensions, swift-protocols

I have the following:

```
protocol Guard {

    var prisoners: Array<Prisoner>? { get set }

    func smack<T: Prisoner>(prisoner: T)

    func smackAll()


}

extension Guard {

    final func smackAll() {

        prisoners?.forEach() { smack($0) }

        //ERROR: "Cannot invoke 'smack' with an argument list of type '(Prisoner)'"

    }

}

protocol Prisoner {

    var guards: Array<Guard>? { get set }

}

extension Prisoner {

   final func incurBeating() {

        guards?.forEach() { $0.smack(self) }

    }

}
```

I wish to assign the `Guard` protocol to any number of objects of different class types, and `Prisoner` to other objects. The objects acting as guards will have their own smack implementations, according to their class type. But I see no reason to re-write `smackAll` in each class that might inherit `Guard`. So I'm trying to do it like this, but the compiler isn't letting me. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following seems to work for me.

```
protocol Guard {
    var prisoners: Array<Prisoner>? { get set }
    func smack<Prisoner>(prisoner: Prisoner)
    func smackAll()
}

extension Guard {
    func smackAll() {
        prisoners?.forEach() { smack($0) }
         //ERROR: "Cannot invoke 'smack' with an argument list of type '(Prisoner)'"
    }
}

protocol Prisoner {
     var guards: Array<Guard>? { get set }
}
```

Note: func smack(prisoner: Prisoner) you don't need to use T: Prisoner. It's already an interface and can be referred to the interface, it won't let you put anything in there that isn't a Prisoner implementer anyway. The only case you would use this is to add more constraint to a concrete class like T: Where MyConcrete implements Prisoner

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I think I was trying to use generics in the wrong way for what I wanted to do ( I only discovered them today when I had a use for them ).